# How to change interval of yticks to not equally range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to draw a plot like the graph below

[image]

As the top plot, ytick is [1,10,100,1000,10000,...]. It's not the same and ten times for each point. I want to do this because 0 group and 1 group is imbalance and 1 is too small to 0.

If I'm not scale, group 1 is near zero.

Please help me.

Thank a lot.

Comment: look into (semi)log plots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a log scale so just add:

```
plt.yscale('log')
```